# Data format issue from .xls to csv in Linux

Tags: linux

I have converted from .xls files to .csv format using the unoconv command on Linux. I have noticed that the format of the decimal value was changed from comma (,) to dot (.).

I have tried the following options using the below commands.

**Command:**

```
for input in /test/test_file.xls; do
    unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,0" --stdout $input | tail -n +6
done  > /test/model.csv
```

**Input file data (.XLS)**

```
killos;water;50,234,00
killos;oil;83,3
piloks;gas;72,2
```

**After conversion (.CSV)**

```
killos;water;50.234.00
killos;oil;83.3
piloks;gas;72.2
```

Note: Column separator as `;` (Semi-colon). Everything is working fine except this numeric value issue.

Comment: This doesn't look like an [xls file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats). An I see that too, it changed `,` to `.`. And what is your question?

Comment: The change of the thousands separator will depend on your LOCALE. This question is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is .xls file only, i don't know why it was converted from comma to dot.

Comment: It is .xls file only, I don't know why it was converted from comma to dot. It should be convert as it is to from source file values. Don't want to see dot in place of a comma.